# What causes the error "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized” when running an ExecuteNonQuery()?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Every time I tried to connect to the database it give me this error:

`The ConnectionString property has not been initialized`

What can I do to solve this?

Here are my codes:

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = ; Initial Catalog = ; USER ID = ; PASSWORD = ;";                     

    string sql = (@"INSERT INTO (1, 2, 3) VALUES('"+1b.Text+"', '"+2b.Text+"','"+3b.Text+"');");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);           
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", 1b.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", 2b.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", 3b.Text);        
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}


private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close(); //<---ExecuteNonQuery error in here
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `Close`? So far I understand the error is on that method

Comment: `Close();` by itself like that, should just close the form.

Comment: Where exactly are you adding the parameters? You seem to be building up the query directly by concatenating.

Comment: Do you use the connection string from your question? Or did you delete Data Source, Initial Catalog etc from your connection string for asking?

Comment: There must be additional code that you aren't showing. Please show all relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change sql command to this form:

> > // see how to use parameters
> >
> > string sql = @"INSERT INTO TableName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES(@p1, @p2, @p3);
> >
> > SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
> >
> > cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 1b.Text);
> >
> > cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 2b.Text);
> >
> > cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", 3b.Text);